# Is there a Maven way to deploy a Java App (not a WebApp)?

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins, cloudbees

I am developing a simple command line application. I would like to use CloudBees to:

- Git repo (OK, even a private one)
- Jenkins Continuous Build (OK, trigger the build when I push to the repo, perfect)
- Deploy to RUN@Cloud (OK, but painful SDK installation)

My question would be: is there a way to deploy a Java App (not a Web App) with the Maven CloudBees plugin ?  (It is also to record my experience).

Running a raw Java container is documented: http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Java+Container

The `bees-maven-plugin` is documented here: https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/MavenGuide . But the plugin does not seems to do all what the SDK can do. So I couldn't use it in Jenkins.

What I did is adding a "Script Shell / Post build step" in the Jenkins job. With the following script:

```
. /private/brnvrn/scripts/setup-sdk
bees app:deploy -a brnvrn/gdataaccess -t java -R class=com.brnvrn.test.Main -R classpath=gdataaccess.jar target/gdataaccess-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar waitForApplicationStart=false
```

How to install the SDK in Jenkins is explained here: http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Scripting+Bees+SDK+in+Jenkins and here is how to mount DAV directory: http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Mounting+DAV+Repositories. (Just be aware that the files you upload in `/private/` will be available in `/private/$account_name/` ...

I managed to make it work and then realized that there is really no point to deploy a command line App to RUN@Cloud. Still I would like to known if the `bees-maven-plugin` would be able to do the job without all the SDK installation trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The CloudBees maven plugin only supports deployment of WAR files.  As an alternative, you can use the [CloudBees Deployer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cloudbees+Deployer+Plugin) plugin for Jenkins to setup a post-build action to deploy the JAR artifact (this is pre-installed in DEV@cloud Jenkins instances).  You can also use the [CloudBees SDK](https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK) to deploy your JAR artifact (bees app:deploy -a APPID JAR_FILE)